# Python alternative to os.kill with a return code?

Tags: python, linux

Is there an alternative to the os.kill function in Python 3 that will give me a return code? I'd like to verify that a process and it's children actually do get killed before restarting them.

I could probably put a kill -0 loop afterwards or do a subprocess.call(kill -9 pid) if I had to but I'm curious if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you're killing and restarting processes from a Python program, you're Doing It Wrong. Consider using a real process supervision system -- systemd, runit, upstart, etc; it's likely that your operating system has one available out-of-the-box.

Comment: Well-behaved process supervision systems launch the programs they supervise as subprocesses, meaning that they're notified by the operating system -- via `SIGCHLD` -- whenever those programs exit, meaning they have no need to poll (and, if they _do_ poll, they can do so using a `waitpid()`-derivative call, returning detailed metadata). Anything which doesn't take advantage of the parent/child relationship will less efficient, less responsive, have less metadata available (such as exit status or identity of signal causing death), or all of the above.

Comment: The piece of software I'm working with is meant to operate in a systemd environment where systemd is not available (ie CentOS 7 in docker and some oddball chroot stuff I'm working on). It's aping some of the basic functionality of systemctl (read the .service files and do the exec actions) without being fully featured (hence how this situation came up). I ended up putting the kill command (which is meant to be a backup if a service doesn't have an ExecStop option configured) in a while loop which rechecks the process pid. Worked out pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

This question is based on a mistaken understanding of how `kill -9 PID` behaves (or `kill` with any other signal -- even though `-9` can't be overridden by a process's signal handler, it can still be delayed if, for instance, the target is in a blocking syscall).

Thus: `kill -9 "$pid"`, in shell, doesn't tell you when the signal is received either. A return code of 0 just means that the signal was sent, same as what Python's `os.kill()` returning without an exception does.

The underlying `sigaction` call -- invoked by both `os.kill()` and the `kill` shell command -- has no way of returning result information. Thus, that information is not available **in any language**.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. I ended up putting the kill command in a while self.isrunning/attempts < 5 loop (after making a false start using a system call instead) using an attribute I had for something else. Fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

os.kill() sends a signal to the process. The return code will still be sent to the parent process.